# Android Studio could not find any version that matches gradle

Tags: android, gradle

Recently, I have been doing a major refactor in my project where I have built a new project and started to move classes and methods from one project to the other. Along the way, I must have done something wrong that's messed up my project.

When I try to sync/build the project, I get:

Error:

```
Could not find any version that matches com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.11.+.
Required by:
    android_app:appName:unspecified
```

Gradle:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.11.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
    signingConfigs {
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.+'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:+'
    compile project(':libraries:facebook')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.+'
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
    compile files('libs/svg-android.jar')
    compile project(':MyLibrary')
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add repositories:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.11.+'
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked. But can you please explain what on earth jcenter() is as i've never used or seen that before?

Comment: if this worked you could accept the answer - regarding jcenter: https://plus.google.com/+SebastianoPoggi/posts/C4RoACPzcCd